# PORT FORWADING TPLINK-TL-WR740N

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding, ms-sql

i was up to using my local MSSQL database with my live application so that i can fetch the data from my personal pc from the web application.

i am creating my web application in sailsjs. and i am using `mssql` for connecting with my MSSQL.

i am successfully able to connect mssql on local now its time to make it live , so i put in on heroku server for testing and enbale my port forwarding from router by following these steps:

1) open router

2) going into forwading

3) entering port 1443 for MSSQL

4) using my internal ip adders in ip address

5) enable the drop down option and click save

then i check for my port is open or not at : http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

but it says the port is still close. so i did R&D and turned off my firewall and enble all the ports again by clicking enable all in router but i am still not able to access my port to connect with mssql

please let me know where i am mistaking . my wireless router model is `TP LINK TL-WR740N.` and my internal ip is like `192.168.0.108`

Please guide me i really need to do this working and i've already burnt my whole day doing R&D on it.

my controller code is:

```
/**
 * NewController
 *
 * @module      :: Controller
 * @description :: A set of functions called `actions`.
 *
 *                 Actions contain code telling Sails how to respond to a certain type of request.
 *                 (i.e. do stuff, then send some JSON, show an HTML page, or redirect to another URL)
 *
 *                 You can configure the blueprint URLs which trigger these actions (`config/controllers.js`)
 *                 and/or override them with custom routes (`config/routes.js`)
 *
 *                 NOTE: The code you write here supports both HTTP and Socket.io automatically.
 *
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers
 */

module.exports = {


  /**
   * Action blueprints:
   *    `/new/index`
   *    `/new`
   */
   index: function (req, res) {

    var sql = require('mssql'); 

var config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    //server: 'localhost', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
    server: '192.168.0.108', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
    database: 'Survey',

    options: {
        //encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
        instanceName: 'sa'
    }
}

var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
    // ... error checks
    if(err)
    {
      console.log('Following is the error while connecting to the database....');
      console.log(err);
    }

    // Query

    var request = new sql.Request(connection); // or: var request = connection.request();
    request.query('select * from User_Login', function(err, recordset) {
        // ... error checks

        console.dir(recordset);
    });

    // Stored Procedure

    // var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    // request.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, 10);
    // request.output('output_parameter', sql.VarChar(50));
    // request.execute('procedure_name', function(err, recordsets, returnValue) {
    //     // ... error checks

    //     console.dir(recordsets);
    // });

});




    // Send a JSON response
    // return res.json({
    //   hello: 'world'
    // });
  },




  /**
   * Overrides for the settings in `config/controllers.js`
   * (specific to NewController)
   */
  _config: {}


};
```

**Thanks in advance..**

Comment: According to the [TL-WR740N manual](http://www.tplink.ca/resources/document/TL-WR740N_V5_User_Guide.pdf) you're leaving out a few steps.  On this router, "Forwarding" is just a category, after which you would want to select "Virtual Servers" (**not** "Port Triggering").  You'd also need to select "TCP" or use "Common Service Port".  Also, it's a bad idea to port forward to an address in the DHCP range unless you've already set up Address Reservation.

Comment: The firmware on that particular router isn't great. OpenWrt is available for it and it runs extremely well. http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr740n

Comment: so you suggest me to install updated openwrt firmware of my router? and if yes then I've gone through your given link and i am really confused about how can i do this @JohnnyVegas

Comment: @Jason yes i've added it into the virtual server option and have selected ALL from TCP or UDP options.. and i've also added a static ip in my ipv4 properties in network properties but still not able to access it..

Comment: Give me the full serial number with version on the bottom and I will tell you what file to download - It's a direct firmware replacement installed via your routers firmware update page